# matching text and javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have a text and array of tags. I'm looking for a way to find if the text contains any of the trigger word in the array. If so, write the code word of the tag (the second parameter in the array).

Is there a better way to do so?

```js
var textim = "I need to eat an apple and banna and meat";
 
var tags = [
            ["apple","fruit"],
            ["meat","other"],
            ["orange","fruit"],
            ["banna","fruit"],
            
            
            ];

tags.forEach(function(entry) {

  if(textim.includes(entry[0])){
    console.log(entry[1]);
  };

});
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to ask this question in CodeReview site - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Looks good to me. Why'd you ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `tags` array to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) `textim` by space, and iterates the words with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). If the `tagsMap` has the word, get the words' value and `console.log()` it:

```js
const textim = "I need to eat an apple and banna and meat";

const tags = [
  ["apple", "fruit"],
  ["meat", "other"],
  ["orange", "fruit"],
  ["banna", "fruit"],
];

const tagsMap = new Map(tags);

textim.split(' ')
  .forEach((word) => {
    if (tagsMap.has(word)) console.log(tagsMap.get(word));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Always iterate through input(textim) and check/match in reference stack but never iterate through reference (tags) array/stack and check in input, otherwise you will end up doing overhead iteration.

Ex: With your current fix, if you have tags array of 100 elements
1) for input text with 5 words - it will iterate 100 times.
2) for input text with 2 words - it will iterate 100 times.

Comment: textim is like 1000 words and the tag was 500